# Dialog Box of jquery ui

Tags: php, javascript, jquery-ui

How can i use the dialog box to show some php content.
I am using jquery ui dialog box, I have a html table, in which i m getting values from database using a while loop: The loop code is:

```
    <?php
     $i=0;
    while ($i < $num) {

    $f1=mysql_result($result,$i,"FullName");
    $Name = $f1;
    $f2=mysql_result($result,$i,"EmailAddr");
    $string=mysql_result($result,$i,"Message");
    $limit=10;
    $string1 = myTruncate($string,$limit);

    ?>
    <tr>
    <td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f1; ?></font></td>
    <td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f2; ?></font></td>
    <td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $string1; ?></font>
    <div id="dialog" title="<?php echo $f1; ?>">
    <a id="stringText" href="" onclick="showStringOutput()" >View Complete</a>
    </div>
    </td>

    </tr>

    <?php
      $i++;
     }
    ?>
    </table>
```

The showStringOutput Function is

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
  function showStringOutput() {
     var stringToOutput = <?php echo $string; ?> + '';
     $('#stringText').text(stringToOutput);    
       }
  </script>
```

I want the dialog box to show The FullName of user, in title, and the complete message when click on View Complete in the dialogbox body. Please help anybody

Comment: What's the actual HTML output?

Comment: Sorry, i dnt understand.. When i click on view Complete, it shows a lightbox< but nothing inside that.

Comment: What is the output of $string?

Comment: Text. A message, for example.. Helllo How r u

Comment: Which lightbox are you using?

Answer (score 2):

onclick="string" won't do anything.  I'm not familiar with LightBox but the code below should at least hookup to the event and alert the text.

Try this:

```
 $(function) () {
       $( "#dialog-modal" ).dialog({
      height: 140,
      modal: true
       });
    });

    function showStringOutput() {
       var stringToOutput = <?php echo $string ?> + '';
       $('#stringText').text(stringToOutput);    
    }

<div id="dialog-modal" title="Basic modal dialog">
    <p id="stringText"></p>
</div>
```

onclick="showStringOutput()"

Comment: The alert command is working fine, The complete string is shown in the message box, Now i want to show that text in the Message Box, alert window in Dialog box of jquery ui, through this line <a id="dialog" href="" onclick="<?php echo $string; ?>" >View Complete</a></td>   , If u are familiar with jquery ui control Dialog, Please help me, how can i pass the message to the dialog box

Comment: I've modified the answer to give you a very basic approach to getting the text in a jQuery UI dialog.

Comment: I have used ur code above, I want to show the result in a table row like this: <tr>
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f1; ?></font></td>
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f2; ?></font></td>
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $string1; ?></font>
<div id="dialog" title="<?php echo $f1; ?>">
<a id="stringText" href="" onclick="showStringOutput()" >View Complete</a>
</div>
</td>

</tr>  This Code returns a dialog as the page opens, & shows ViewComplete in the body of dialog.. Can't get out of this, what to do.

Comment: I have modified the Question to show the complete code, i am using.

Comment: This isn't how I'd do it but since you don't seem to be making any attempt on your own.  <font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><span id="stuff"></span></font>  then in the javascript     function showStringOutput() {
       var stringToOutput = <?php echo $string ?> + '';
       $('#stuff').text(stringToOutput);    
    }

Comment: Nthing Happens. Same thing. I want to do all this on viewComplete Click event, I am very new to php, just learning, You can see the complete scenario at this http://team-kh.hireexpertprogrammers.com/~maiarn/Admin.php   Hope u understand

Comment: $("a#button1").click(function(e) {

            e.preventDefault();
            $("#dialog1").dialog();
            showStringOutput();
        });